# Fastest algorithm to determine if matrix has maximum rank

Tags: algorithm, matrix, rank

What is the fastest algorithm to determine if an N x N matrix has rank N?
In my case, I need an algorithm that is optimal for N around the order of 30. Is there any better way than computing the determinant, and check if it's not zero? I have the feeling that somehow the determinant of a matrix adds some information with respect to the rank.. and I don't even want to know the rank, I just would like to see if it's maximum.

Comment: What type are the matrix entries?

Comment: The entries in my matrix are integers.

Comment: You can do better than O(N^3): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-determine-if-a-matrix-is-invertible

Comment: @ChrisK If only we could close this as a duplicate of that one. But since we can't, perhaps you'd like to write up a short answer with the best response from there?